# Strange behavior of WebClient.DownloadStringAsync in Win8 (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, webclient

I came across a problem in my program when I run it on Win8 (it runs fine on WinXP). I will be grateful if anyone can give some ideas about what's going on. It seems that some network settings have been changed between WinXP and Win8.

Here I made sample code that causes weird things for me:

HttpListener listening locally for port 20000

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create listener
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:20000/");
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");

        // Wait for request
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        // Create response
        string responseString = GenerateString();
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
        response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

        // Send response 
        System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        output.Close();
        listener.Stop();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GenerateString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6000000; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("A");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

WebClient downloading string from port 20000

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        //c.Proxy = null;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start downloading: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
                c.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,a) => OnDownloadStringCompleted(s,a);
                c.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:20000"), c);
                //c.DownloadString(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:20000"));
                //Console.WriteLine("Finish downloading: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        Console.ReadLine();

        c.Dispose();
    }

    private static void OnDownloadStringCompleted(object s, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs arg)
    {
        try
        {
            string response = arg.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Finish downloading: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

If I run this on my XP machine it works fine (WebClient downloads string asynchronously). If I run this on Win8 machine (I tried 2 machines with Win8 and Win8.1) then it depends on size of the string I pass to HttpListenerResponse.OutputStream - say, for small response string of 100000 chars it works fine, but for 6000000 chars it only works sometimes and sometimes throws errors: either "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" or "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:20000".

Another strange thing is that sync DownloadString (commented there) seems to work fine on Win8!

Actually, it's so weird that I'm a bit lost. I'm not sure why it works sometimes, but seems that it works first time after I build it and then stops working.

Things I've tried so far:
1. Disabling Windows firewall - didn't help
2. Playing with localhost<->127.0.0.1 (Win8 seems to change policy about DNS, so localhost may work slower or not work without changing hosts). Both 127.0.0.1 and localhost work in this strange way.
3. Running code from Administrator and from user - also didn't help.

Did anyone experienced this thing or do you have some clues?

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention: either of the system I use has .NET 4.0 installed

Comment: Also, I tried changing Proxy property of WebClient to null or WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy, but still it didn't change anything.